# Query for showing missing years

Tags: select, ms-access

I have a question about showing the missing values by a query.

Given table named `Top2000` with fields `Artist`, `Title`, `Ranking`, `Year`, the following query...

```
Select * 
from Top2000 
order by Artist, Title, Year
```

...shows something like...

```
Abba | Dancing Queen       | 1720 | 2015
Abba | Dancing Queen       | 1340 | 2016
Abba | Dancing Queen       | 1970 | 2019
Abba | Money, Money, Money | 870  | 2016
Abba | Money, Money, Money | 502  | 2017
```

...while the next query...

```sql
select distinct Year 
from Top2000 
order by Year
```

...gives results like...

```
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
```

I want to create a query with the following output

```
Abba | Dancing Queen       | 2017
Abba | Dancing Queen       | 2018
Abba | Money, Money, Money | 2015
Abba | Money, Money, Money | 2018
Abba | Money, Money, Money | 2019
```

How do I write such a query?

Comment: what is the calculation base for replacing the years contained in the datasets with the desired years - and WHY - wouldn't it be more useful to correct false data (via update) if the years are wrong ? - Those years aren't  "missing"

Comment: Dear eagle275,

The tabel top2000 shows the ranking of the popsongs for every year the song has a ranking. Because of the changing preferenses of the voters a song is not necesserely ranked every year. I want to creatie an overview of every popsong in the table with the years the song has not been ranked. I don’t want to update the table top2000.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarification - unfortunately MS-Access (and SQL-Server put up some limits ..

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

So I only have a "half" solution for you

```
SELECT DISTINCT Year 
FROM Top2000 AS T3
WHERE Year NOT IN (
  SELECT Distinct Year FROM Top2000 AS T1 
   WHERE T1.Artist='Abba' AND T1.Title='Money, Money, Money'
)
```

with this you would have to first get a cleaned list of all unique Artist-Title pairs - then call the query with the Artist and Title filled in instead of the example I used from your sample data.

Problem is that databases are way better suited to give you results about data they actually contain instead of data they don't "know"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have experienced the same limitations of MS-Access you mentioned. At this moment I try to fix it with a subquery for every year not ranked and a union to combine everything.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work (I use dummy data in @tbl and not your Top2000 table):

```
--Dummy table
declare @tbl table(a varchar(max) not null,b varchar(max) not null,c integer not null,d integer not null)

--Dummy data
insert into @tbl(a,b,c,d) values('Abba','Dancing Queen',1720,2015)
insert into @tbl(a,b,c,d) values('Abba','Dancing Queen',1340,2016)
insert into @tbl(a,b,c,d) values('Abba','Dancing Queen',1970,2019)
insert into @tbl(a,b,c,d) values('Abba','Money, Money, Money',870,2016)
insert into @tbl(a,b,c,d) values('Abba','Money, Money, Money',502,2017)

--Start year( you need to know the first year in the list)
declare @minYear integer
set @minYear = (select MIN(d) from @tbl)

--Table to hold the result
    declare @res table(a varchar(max) not null,b varchar(max) not null,d integer not null)

while @minYear < YEAR(dateadd(year,1,sysdatetime()))
    begin
    insert into @res(a,b,d)
    select a,b,@minYear
    from @tbl y
    where y.a not in( select X.a from @tbl x where x.b = y.b and x.d = @minYear )
    group by a,b

    set @minYear = @minYear +1
    end

select * from @res
```

Comment: I will try to translate your code into VBA for MS Access. I assume the equivalant of @tbl in your cod in VBA is a recordset.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on an answer to my own question:

First i created a query for every year in table *top2000*. The queries have been saved with the name *Qry20xx*

for example *Qry2015*:

```
 **SELECT** T.artist, T.title, T.Year
 **FROM** Top2000 AS T
 **WHERE** (((T.Year)=2015));
```

Then I created a query with *Top2000* and *Qry2015*

1. relate with a left join
2. test on null
3. every result gets extra expression *Year not ranked* with the value 2015

   ```
   **SELECT DISTINCT** Top2000.Artist, Top2000.Title, 2015 AS [Year not Ranked]
   **FROM** Top2000 **LEFT JOIN** Qry2015 **ON** (Top2000.Title = Qry2015.title) 
   **AND** Top2000.Artist = Qry2015.artist)
   **WHERE** (((Qry2015.artist) Is Null) 
   **AND** ((Qry2015.title) Is Null));
   ```

Then I repeated this for every year and merged them with **union**

```
    **Union**
    (...)
    **Union**
    **SELECT DISTINCT** Top2000.Artist, Top2000.Title, 2019 AS [Year not Ranked]
    **FROM** Top2000 **LEFT JOIN** Qry2019 **ON** (Top2000.Title = Qry2019.title) 
    **AND** (Top2000.Artist = Qry2019.artist)
    **WHERE** (((Qry2019.artist) Is Null) **AND** ((Qry2019.title) Is Null))
    **ORDER BY** 1, 2, 3;
```

This solution is not very flexible because next year I have to make modifications to the query next year after inserting the records for 2020.